# Directory diff with text file output

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, diff

It appears I was unable to save the scripts I used for converting some Subversion repos to Mercurial ones, more specifically the filemaps.

How can I get diffs between two directories (added/removed directories, files, etc.) with the results provided in a text file?

Comment: `DIR /b /s [subversion_directory] > svndir.txt & DIR /b /s [mercurial_directory] > hgdir.txt & [your_diff_tool] svndir.txt hgdir.txt`

Comment: How does that print the differences? Lets say there is a difference, everything after that will be wrong (even if it should be marked as same)

Comment: @zb226 -- I'm thinking both must be sorted the same

Comment: @DanH: You're correct, `/o:n` for sorting should be added to both `dir` commands.

Comment: @zb226 - Would you mind converting these comments to an actual answer? I did that with KDiff3 and it partly did the trick (I still had to format it the way it should), so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a full-fledged diff tool like [diffmerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) or [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) (both free) you can easily check the differences by comparing the output files of the following batch file. As it is, you need to provide the two directories as arguments, but you may as well set those directly in the `SET dir...` lines - e.g. `SET dir1=c:\svn` and `SET dir2=c:\hg`. The script removes the path prefix from the filenames which would otherwise differ on all lines.

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET dir1=%1
SET dir2=%2
ECHO. 2>dir1.txt
ECHO. 2>dir2.txt
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%F IN ('DIR /s /b /o:n %dir1%') DO ( 
    SET tmp=%%F
    ECHO !tmp:%dir1%\=! >> dir1.txt
)
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%F IN ('DIR /s /b /o:n %dir2%') DO ( 
    SET tmp=%%F
    ECHO !tmp:%dir2%\=! >> dir2.txt
)
EndLocal
```

Then just diff the two output files `dir1.txt` and `dir2.txt`:

```
kdiff3 dir1.txt dir2.txt
```